# Python List Index Out Of Range Error with Folder Organizing Program

Tags: python

Okay so I've been at this for a while, looking at tutorials and forums to try and figure out what's wrong here, but I just keep getting the same "IndexError: list index out of range" error. I'm trying to make a program that will sort all the files in a particular folder into another organized folder. (Taking, say, the Downloads folder and creating a bunch of folders inside where the organized files can live clutter-free).

Here is my code:

```
import os
    import shutil

    path = "D:/Python Programs/Automatic File Sorter"
    names = os.listdir(path)
    folder_name = ["Images", "Videos", "Documents", "exe", "misc"]

    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    d = 0

    img = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".rw2", ".xcf", ".xmp"]
    video = [".WEBM" ".MPG", ".MP2", ".MPEG", ".MTS", ".MPE", ".flv", ".MPV", ".OGG", ".MP4", ".M4P", ".M4V", ".AVI", ".WMV", ".MOV", ".QT", ".FLV", ".SWF", ".AVCHD"]
    doc = [".txt", ".docx", ".pdf", ".pds", ".xlsx", ".pptm", ".obj", ".mtl", ".stl"]
    exe = [".exe", ".msi"]

    for x in range (0, 5):
        if not os.path.exists(path + "/" + folder_name[x]):
        os.makedirs(path + "/" + folder_name[x])

    x = 0
    i = 0

    for x in names[i]:

        print("a: " + str(a))
        print("b: " + str(b))
        print("c: " + str(c))
        print("d: " + str(d))
        print("i: " + str(i))

    if i <= len(names):

        if a <= 5:
            if img[a] in names[i] and not os.path.exists(path + "/" + "Images" + names[i]):
                shutil.move(path + "/", path + "/" + "Images/" + names[i])
                a += 1

        if b <= 18:
            if video[b] in names[i] and not os.path.exists(path + "/" + "Videos" + names[i]):
                shutil.move(path + "/", path + "/" + "Videos/" + names[i])
                b += 1

        if c <= 8:
            if doc[c] in names[i] and not os.path.exists(path + "/" + "Documents" + names[i]):
                shutil.move(path + "/", path + "/" + "Documents/" + names[i])
                c += 1

        if d <= 1:
            if exe[d] in names[i] and not os.path.exists(path + "/" + "exe" + names[i]):
                shutil.move(path + "/", path + "/" + "exe/" + names[i])
                d += 1

        i += 1
```

When I run this only `i` increases in value, not the other variables. The other if statements aren't able to run because `names[i]` is out of range for some reason. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the names are the list of directories.
So

`for x in names` not `for x in names[i]` and there are no need to add everywhere `names[i]` you can just replace it with `x`. last, there is no need to increase `i+=1`

Correct code will be something like this:

```
import os
    import shutil

    path = "D:/Python Programs/Automatic File Sorter"
    names = os.listdir(path)
    folder_name = ["Images", "Videos", "Documents", "exe", "misc"]

    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    d = 0

    img = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".rw2", ".xcf", ".xmp"]
    video = [".WEBM" ".MPG", ".MP2", ".MPEG", ".MTS", ".MPE", ".flv", ".MPV", ".OGG", ".MP4", ".M4P", ".M4V", ".AVI", ".WMV", ".MOV", ".QT", ".FLV", ".SWF", ".AVCHD"]
    doc = [".txt", ".docx", ".pdf", ".pds", ".xlsx", ".pptm", ".obj", ".mtl", ".stl"]
    exe = [".exe", ".msi"]

    for x in range (0, 5):
        if not os.path.exists(path + "/" + folder_name[x]):
        os.makedirs(path + "/" + folder_name[x])

    for x in names:

        print("a: " + str(a))
        print("b: " + str(b))
        print("c: " + str(c))
        print("d: " + str(d))

        if a <= 5:
            if img[a] in x and not os.path.exists(path + "/" + "Images" + x):
                shutil.move(path + "/", path + "/" + "Images/" + x)
                a += 1

        if b <= 18:
            if video[b] in x and not os.path.exists(path + "/" + "Videos" + x):
                shutil.move(path + "/", path + "/" + "Videos/" + x])
                b += 1

        if c <= 8:
            if doc[c] in x and not os.path.exists(path + "/" + "Documents" + x):
                shutil.move(path + "/", path + "/" + "Documents/" + x)
                c += 1

        if d <= 1:
            if exe[d] in x and not os.path.exists(path + "/" + "exe" + x):
                shutil.move(path + "/", path + "/" + "exe/" + x)
                d += 1
```

Comment: Okay so I updated my code and your answer worked, but then I was getting a WinError 5 meaning i didn't have permission to move the files. To fix this i decided to switch from using shutil to using os.rename to move the files, which fixed the problem except none of the files move into the proper folders. Now the if statements say "os.rename(path + "/", path + "/" + "Images/" + x)" instead of shutil and i moved the a+= 1 etc. to the end of the for statement so they aren't inside each if statement seperately

Comment: if mistakes pointed out were really there then feel free to accept it as the answer. thanks